# systemd/cgroup resource limits -- different behaviour between hosts

Tags: systemd, cgroups, limit, systemctl

I'm heavily confused. I have a physical server running Ubuntu 20.04 and a `vagrant` (VirtualBox) virtual machine also running Ubuntu 20.04. Both are running with `hwe` 5.13 kernel and `systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.17)` On both of them I set `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` to use `cgroup-v2`. After reboot on both of them `cgroup-v2` is mounted and there is no `v1`, so a clean `v2` systems.

### The first problem

The first difference is in enabled default controllers. `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control`:

- `cpuset cpu io memory pids` on the virtual machine
- `io memory pids` on the physical machine

First question: Why? :) And how to control which controllers are enabled by default? I try to set `DefaultCPUAccounting=yes` but this does not help. And `echo "+cpu" >> ...` is only temporary.

### The second problem

I tried to set limits using `cgroup`. I decided to limit IO bandwith using `IOWriteBandwidthMax` and test this using `dd`.

```
sudo systemctl set-property --runtime user-1000.slice IOWriteBandwidthMax="/home 20M"
```

And then:

```
dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=kamil.test bs=1M count=2000
```

- This works on the virtual machine:

  ```
  2079326208 bytes (2.1 GB, 1.9 GiB) copied, 102 s, 20.4 MB/s
  2000+0 records in
  2000+0 records out
  2097152000 bytes (2.1 GB, 2.0 GiB) copied, 102.964 s, 20.4 MB/s
  ```
- But not on the physical host:

  ```
  2000+0 przeczytanych rekordów
  2000+0 zapisanych rekordów
  skopiowane 2097152000 bajtów (2,1 GB, 2,0 GiB), 1,10876 s, 1,9 GB/s
  ```

The limits are set properly: `systemctl cat user-1000.slice`:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/10-defaults.conf
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=User Slice of UID %j
Documentation=man:user@.service(5)
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Slice]
TasksMax=33%

# /run/systemd/system.control/user-1000.slice.d/50-CPUQuota.conf
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Slice]
CPUQuota=

# /run/systemd/system.control/user-1000.slice.d/50-IOWriteBandwidthMax.conf
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Slice]
IOWriteBandwidthMax=
IOWriteBandwidthMax=/home 20000000
```

Why oh why this works on the virtual machine and not on the physical machine? (Both users have UID `1000` and both commands are run in their respective home directories). I'm lost here and kindly ask for an explanation :)

**EDIT: 18:20**

When I add the `oflag=sync` to `dd`, the the limiting works. Without the flag it is full 2 GB/s. I set `/home 5M`:

```
dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=kamil.test bs=1M count=2000 oflag=sync 
skopiowane 614465536 bajtów (614 MB, 586 MiB), 123 s, 5,0 MB/s^C
586+0 przeczytanych rekordów
586+0 zapisanych rekordów
skopiowane 614465536 bajtów (614 MB, 586 MiB), 123,062 s, 5,0 MB/s
```

I suspect some form of caching. When creating a file is almost instant, calling the `sync` command hangs the shell -- it probably waits for the transfer. `systemd-cgtop` shows several MB/s in my slice in this time.

Kind Regards